# elasticsearch exact match with dashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

We have an index of domain names in elasticsearch (we are using the tire gem with ruby to connect and maintain this) however we are having trouble with exact searches.

If I search for the term google.com in domains, it brings back google.com however it also brings back any domain with a dash (-) in such as in-google.com, [research](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Searching-on-terms-with-dashes-td2836091.html) leads me to believe that - is a wildcard in ES and all I need to do is put not_analyzed but that doesn't work.

```
    :domain       => { :type => 'string' , :analyzer => 'whitespace'                          },
    :domain_2     => { :type => 'string' , :analyzer => 'pattern'                          },
    :domain_3     => { :type => 'string', :index => 'not_analyzed'                           },
    :domain_4     => { :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'snowball'                            }
```

I've tried different analysers as you can see above, but they all have the same issue when searched using the 'head' plugin'.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8080839 is the code I'm using to generate the dataset to test with, what I'm looking for is the ability to search for JUST google and if I want *google  I can implement my own wildcard?

I'm resigned to the fact that I'm going to have to delete and regenerate my index but no matter what analyser I choose or type, I still cannot get an exact match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not showing the sample queries you are using. Are you sure your queries and indexing uses the same text processing?

Also, you may want to check out the [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-multi-field-type.html)-approach to analyzing things multiple ways.

I've made a runnable example with a bunch of different queries that illustrate this. Note that the domain has been indexed in two ways, and note which field the queries are hitting: https://www.found.no/play/gist/ecc52fad687e83ddcf73

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "domain": {
                    "type": "multi_field",
                    "fields": {
                        "domain": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "standard"
                        },
                        "whitespace": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "analyzer": "whitespace"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'


# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"domain":"google.com"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"domain":"in-google.com"}
'

# Do searches

# Matches both
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "_all": "google.com"
        }
    }
}
'

# Also matches "google.com". in-google.com gets tokenized to ["in", "google.com"]
# and the default match operator is `or`.
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "domain": {
                "query": "in-google.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
'

# What terms are generated? (Answer: `google.com` and `in`)
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "size": 0,
    "facets": {
        "domain": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "domain"
            }
        }
    }
}
'

# This should just match the second document.
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "domain.whitespace": {
                "query": "in-google.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for answering, I'm a little unsure I understand your example, I've setup the index as you've suggested with the multi_field approach (thanks for that) however I'm still having issues searching for the exact domain, the two example queries you give still display in-google.com even though the search query is just google.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the comments get lost in the export. If you look at the play, there should be comments as to why they are included. The last query only matches in-google.com. I've updated the answer to include more clarifying comments. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm starting to understand this (and Play) a bit more, https://www.found.no/play/gist/dd354aad8703837877cf this is my current work in progress with a bit more data, as you can see I've got the exact matches working well, however it's now wildcard searches, if I want to search for google*, in-google still appears as does megoogle.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, it's not fully there but it sets me on the road

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want in all the search examples in the play, but you can't use wildcards in a `match`-query. In some cases there you want the `prefix`-query. (Note that prefix doesn't do analysis). The IP-filter is slightly odd. There is the `ip_range`-filter that can deal with CIDR-masks, but nothing like the pattern you attempted. You'll need to index the IP in multiple ways to do the query you want.

Comment: Ah I see, IP needs to be a range, that's fine. I'll look into the prefix now